# Related Rates of perpendicular motion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

Two objects *A* and *B* are connected by a rigid rod that has a length *L*. The objects slide along perpendicular guide rails. If *A* slides to the left with a constant speed *v*, what is the velocity of *B* when *a*=60$^\circ$?

I know the answer is .566 *v*, but I am completely unsure why.

---

I have tried saying that 
$$
y=L*sin(a), dy/da=d/da L*sina,dy/da=L cosa,dy/da=Lcos60=L/2
$$
but that obviously is the wrong aproach, since I need $dy/dt$, not $dy/da$.

Comment: What is $a$ supposed to be?

Comment: *a* is the angle formed by the rod and the *x-axis*

Comment: Okay, but you also haven't stated which object goes on which axis, though since A slides to the left I'm guessing A is on the x-axis?

Comment: Correct. There's a diagram, but I thought it was extraneous. Sorry, a is on the x, b is on the y.

Comment: Updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

$x^2+y^2 = z^2$

where $x$ is the location of A with respect to where the rails meet, and $y$ is the location of B with respect to the same spot. And $z^2$ is just L, the length of the rod, which is constant.

Differentiate this wrt to $t$, and you get

$2x \frac{dx}{dt}+ 2y \frac{dy}{dt} = 0$

We know the angle is 60 degrees, so we can determine what $x$ and $y$ should be using $y=Lsin(\theta)$ and $x=Lcos(\theta)$. We also know $\frac{dx}{dt}=v$.

Plug in, solve for $\frac{dy}{dt}$

Comment: Thanks so much! Forgot that we know both x and y, and also a bit of how to do partial differentiation.